# mysql query update first occurance of parameters

Tags: mysql, database

I have mysql table that lists out what sections of a website a user belongs to and whether they have admin privliges (admin = 1 or admin = 0, and basic = 1 or basic = 0).

I am wanting to give the first user the database find of each section admin privileges I want to do this through mySQL.

Is there away and I can select the first user of each section and give them admin privileiges?

So my table looks like this for example

**SECTION_USER**

|--ID--|--USER_ID--|--SECTION_ID--|--ADMIN--|--BASIC--|
|-- 1--|-------100----    |-------------999----     |----0--------|-----1------|
|-- 2--|-------101----    |-------------999----     |----0--------|-----1------|
|-- 3--|-------102----    |-------------100----     |----0--------|-----1------|
|-- 4--|-------103----    |-------------100----     |----0--------|-----1------|

So basically the query would update user 100 to admin and user 102 to admin as they are the first results for section 999 and section 100.

Comment: When you say "first` what exact order do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

```
update section_user su
join 
(
   select section_id, min(id) as id
   from section_user
   group by section_id
) tmp on tmp.section_id = su.section_id
     and tmp.id = su.id
set admin = 1
```

The inner select gets each section and the first (MIN) user of each one. If you join on that result you can update the table.